# Show / Hide Calendar control on selection of item in radiobutton list?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can I show the calendar control and text box control only when selecting the "Select date" in radiobuttonlist control ?

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_immediate_date_view_2" CssClass="gp-contact-us-radiolist" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem>Immediate</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Select date</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calendar_view_2" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" PopupButtonID="rbl_immediate_date_view_2" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

In my markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_immediate_date_view_2" 
        CssClass="gp-contact-us-radiolist" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="rbl_immediate_date_view_2_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Immediate</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Select date</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calendar_view_2"  TargetControlID="txtStartDate" PopupButtonID="rbl_immediate_date_view_2" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Now in my code behind:

```
protected void rbl_immediate_date_view_2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtStartDate.Visible = rbl_immediate_date_view_2.SelectedValue == "Select date";
}
```